# Unable to connect to Google cloud SQL via Java eclipse

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sql

I'm having trouble to connect to my database from eclipse using my instance a google cloud sql database.
I successed to access to the database via mysql command line but no in eclise.

My code:

```
String instanceConnectionName = "****";
String databaseName = "****";
String username = "***";
String password = "***";

 String jdbcUrl = String.format(
            "jdbc:mysql://google/%s?cloudSqlInstance=%s&"
        + "socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory",
            databaseName,
            instanceConnectionName);         
 Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);
```

The Error I get:

```
jdbc:mysql://google/****?cloudSqlInstance=****e&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory

May 03, 2017 10:53:07 AM com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory connect
INFO: Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [****].
May 03, 2017 10:53:07 AM com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SslSocketFactory getInstance
INFO: First Cloud SQL connection, generating RSA key pair.
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:917)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2332)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at neviTracker.program.ProgramConnections.main(ProgramConnections.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to obtain credentials to communicate with the Cloud SQL API
at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SslSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:545)
at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SslSocketFactory.getInstance(SslSocketFactory.java:138)
at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory.connect(SocketFactory.java:47)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:298)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286)
... 13 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running on Google App Engine, Google Compute Engine, or Google Cloud Shell. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:98)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:213)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:191)
at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SslSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:543)
... 18 more
```

Comment: did you make it sure that your MySQL service is up and running?

Comment: Yes @patateskafa

Answer (score 2):

You have an error message that says the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is not set. Please create a `.credentials` file in a root folder and add your credential details in it.

Please refer to this link
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials

Answer (score 2):

> The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running on Google App Engine, Google Compute Engine, or Google Cloud Shell. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

You need credentials to access google cloud sql. You can create from [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/)

After creating your credential, create your key file and point it in your bash_profile(read the block quote for more info). then it should work

Alternatively you can use **CLOUD SQL PROXY** to not work with environment variables, follow the steps in this link, if something is blurry please ask. 
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy

hope this helps.